# Netbeans or Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3?

Tags: netbeans-7, sun

We have a C++ application that runs on Solaris. There are no plans of porting it to other platforms as of now.

Assuming that you have to choose between Netbeans 7 (or higher) and Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 as an IDE, which one would you go for?

The following are the essential requirements that should be met:

- Better IDE Integration with Subversion source control (Checkin,
  Checkout, Diff and Merge files from within IDE)
- Better debugging performance.
- Code Navigation performance (Some of the individual source files we
  have are of 1MB or more)
- Support for remote development(Remote checkout/check in etc)
- Ability to extend the IDE through plugins.

The fact that both of the IDEs are based on the same code base, is making the choice difficult.
Sun Studio is tightly integrated with Solaris in a good way. On the other hand Netbeans has more momentum and frequent bug fixes/releases.

Any thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ development and all the versioning and other stuff you mention I'd add a 3rd option... Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements its a tough call. Personally, I would select Solaris Studio.
Studio gives you all the compilers and debugging tools in the "box", along with some pretty
powerful performance analysis tools. And, in the latest version, it is integrating into the Solaris IPS mechanism so it makes it easy to install and upgrade.